# How can I leverage SaaS web app styles in an external application?

Tags: sass, external

Our web app uses SASS exclusively.

We use a MVC architecture to render documents in HTML and we seek to provide pdfs of those documents using a third party (typeset.sh)  web service to render the PDFs.

The desired outcome is that the external pdf generator uses the webapp v2style.css to render properly.

What options can you suggest to get SASS styles in the generated PDFs?

The html generated uses a web addressable URL from our webapp for the SASS stylesheet (v2style.css), but the styles are not applied.  Specifically, SASS generates a v2style.css directory containing v2style.css.map. Inspecting v2style.css.map shows there are relative links (../../..) to the folder where SASS is managed.  I suspect this the root cause of the failure.